# @Transactional works on public method in service but not with protected method

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, transactional

I am trying to call a service method(B) from another service method(A) from same service impl class. Now when I put @Transactional on #A, everything works fine, but when I put the same on #B everything breaks apart. And the error that I get is

```
Exception: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: MyEntity.childs, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at <reference to my code>
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at <reference to my code>
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:483) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.RC1.jar:2.0.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at <reference to my code>
        at <reference to my code>
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at <reference to my code>
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: MyEntity.childs, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:561) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at <reference to my code>
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

My class call structure is like this
[image]

A = fail case
B = success case

doProcessS() ==> public void
doSubProcessS() ==> protected void

I am using SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE

I want to execute everything in 'A' way and not 'B' as I want to execute another check in doProcessS() based on data committed to DB in doSubProcess()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` is based on `Spring AOP`

Spring AOP does not work in self-invocation method (Within the same class)

You can fix it by mark your `doProcessS()` in `ServiceImpl` as `@Transactional`

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)

> This means that method calls on that object reference will be calls on
>   the proxy, and as such the proxy will be able to delegate to all of
>   the interceptors (advice) that are relevant to that particular method
>   call. However, once the call has finally reached the target object,
>   the SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may
>   make on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be
>   invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has
>   important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to
>   result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a
>   chance to execute.

If you want to separate your transaction, delegate `doSubProcessS` to other class and mark it propagation type as `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`

Comment: Thanks for your response. But why I am trying to do this is because I want some data to be submitted to DB(flushed) before proceeding with my check. This is sort of baseline for me to have data physically in DB before I go for the check.

Comment: If you want to separate your transaction, delegate `doSubProcessS` to other class and mark it propagation type as `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`

Comment: Thank you. Request you to please share a reference link to study as I tried looking for it and it seems something is wrong as they don't get me the correct result. Also, I am new to Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW.

Comment: Read more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

Comment: I tried, but no success :(
The problem I am facing is that after it returns from doSubProcess() in scenario A, the DB is not updated and hence when I try to do a new transaction(read - invoke API in other MS that tries to read latest from DB) at that time, it reads only old data

Comment: Your first comment(...delegate doSubProcessS to other class...) solved my issues hence, request you to please put that into your answer, meanwhile, I am accepting your answer.